# Link in header/footer of MS Word

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

Is it possible to create an actionable link in a MS Word 2011 (Mac OS) header or footer? Specifically, I want to create a "back to table of contents" link at the bottom of each page.

I can make a textbox with a link in it, though this will become tedious in a +100 pg. document...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible apparently. The content within headers and footers is not actionable by design, therefore links will not work. The easiest way to do it is to press CTRL + Home (Windows) or fn+cmd+forward (mac) to go to page 1..